# How i can disable the native camera buttons?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, camera

I need to disable the button, when i enter in the native camera, like portrait, and when i turn like landscape, i need to able the buttons again. How i can do?. In IOS.

Thanks so much.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably easier rather than disabling the buttons (which could be confusing to a user), just to rotate the camera view into landscape when it's opened, and prevent any rotations to portrait. You've got a couple of options for that as well, which might make it easier to develop.